# Allow to prevent current close-voting or reopen-voting without having to wait

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just a quick thought.

Given there is a closed question and someones have casted their re-open votes, but I am sure it should stay closed. What should I do?

I can **wait** until it will gets reopened (**if** it gets reopened) and then cast my (long-awaited?) vote. But why should I wait? Why can't I just cast my "don't" vote before and go?

---

Depending on question state:

1. Question is opened. People can cast there close-votes, but at the same time another people can cast their "don't close" votes if there are more than 0 close-votes already. Until sum reach 3 (or maybe make it a more complex formula) it won't get closed.

This to example could happens after edit: new readers may read updated, refined, better worder, beautiful and worth no closing version, when there are 2 close-votes still awaiting for a last random guy who may be convinced by votes and not by content of what to do and will cast his close vote.

The thing here is what some of folks who think question is good are already done with it. And they will not come again, will not wait until question is closed to cast their re-open vote.

2. Question is closed. People can cast their re-open votes, but at the same time another people can cast there "don't re-open" votes...

.. because maybe question is still bad, because the guy who posted the answer before it was closed (and therefore voting) shouldn't be ever attempting to answer, etc.

---

I am trying to solve following problems by my proposal:

- No need to wait for anything, act immediately. If I see a problem why should I wait until it become "official" problem and only then I am allowed to act?
- It will be harder to close/re-open in bordercases (think of vote-wars or "gray" questions), no need for moderators, profit!

Comment: If users were able to counter re-open votes, then how can you imagine a question gets re-opened?

Comment: @machine_1: by re-open votes outnumbering "keep closed" votes.

Comment: Isn't this basically what happens in the re-open queue?

Comment: @ivarni, providing me with a link to that item in queue would be a solution too.

Comment: @Cerbrus, shall we wait another 5 years?

Comment: @ivarni: kinda, but why not allow the balance to be made on the question, instead of flip-flopping the scale all the time?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, I think that makes more sense, just pointing out that we already have similar systems. Actually I think the mixing of votes on the question and votes from the queue are kind of wierd.

Comment: @ivarni the reopen queue is *not* the only way to cast a reopen vote, though. Anybody who has enough reputation and visits the question directly can cast a reopen vote. However, if you're looking at the question you can't review as "keep closed". Not to my knowledge, at least. Also, unless I'm mistaken voting as "keep closed" in the queue merely removes it from the queue for *now* - the votes still have to expire normally.

Comment: @VLAZ That's the mixing of votes I was talking about. Once it's removed from the queue the votes stay but any flags are cleared. It doesn't really make sense. If this feature request was implemented it would bring the two closer together.

Comment: Geez, I didn't realize that question was 5 years old already